# Eureka client works and communicates with each other even after i stopped the registered server. How?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I have created a Eureka server and registered two clients with it. The clients communicate with each other smoothly.

After that, I stopped the Eureka server but still both my clients are communicating with each other smoothly. How is this possible? I'm using the following code in my 1st client to communicate to the 2nd client.

```
ServiceInstance instance = loadbalancerclient.choose(secondService);
URI uri=URI.create(String.format("http://%s:%s"+"/test",instance.getHost(),instance.getPort()));
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri.toString(),String.class);
```

Since instead of hardcoding any URL I'm using the registered name of the 2nd client in Eureka server, I was not expecting it to work when the server is down. Can anybody explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka does not handle communication between the two servers, only the registration. This means that a service uses Eureka only to find out the address of the other service. After that the communication is done directly between the two services, without Eureka.

If Eureka is down, the client uses a cached copy of the remote service's address, which is good for resilience and temporary network failures.

If you think about it a little, why wouldn't it work? If Eureka is down it doesn't mean that the remote service is also down or that it's physical address has changed.

Answer (score 3):

From Eureka [documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication#fetch-registry):

> **Fetch Registry**
>
> Eureka clients fetches the registry information from the server and
>   caches it locally. After that, the clients use that information to
>   find other services. This information is updated periodically (every
>   30 seconds) by getting the delta updates between the last fetch cycle
>   and the current one. The delta information is held longer (for about 3
>   mins) in the server, hence the delta fetches may return the same
>   instances again. The Eureka client automatically handles the duplicate
>   information.
>
> After getting the deltas, Eureka client reconciles the information
>   with the server by comparing the instance counts returned by the
>   server and if the information does not match for some reason, the
>   whole registry information is fetched again. Eureka server caches the
>   compressed payload of the deltas, whole registry and also per
>   application as well as the uncompressed information of the same. The
>   payload also supports both JSON/XML formats. Eureka client gets the
>   information in compressed JSON format using jersey apache client.